# Как сделать что бы иконка у приложения подстраивалась под фон рабочего стола?

Tags: java, android

На Google Pixel есть функция которая позволяет изменять цвет иконок под картикнку рабочего стола. Как сделать что бы эта иконка поддерживала данную функцию

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive